# How can we show min and max values for candlestick charts using nvd3?

Tags: nvd3.js, candlestick-chart

How can we show min and max values for candlestick charts using nvd3

Comment: Did you try a web search for "How can we show min and max values for candlestick charts using nvd3"?

Comment: Is it that you want to depict it son your chart using a line maybe?

Comment: Did you try chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(true); ?